# Add a small subset of files to GIT and not have a "git pull" command delete all the unversioned files

Tags: wordpress, git

I have been struggling with getting git working effectively for wordpress development without destroying my production working directory due to catastrophic pulls. Initially I would add my entire development directory to git, push to github remote, clone to production and then follow the standard git procedure but this would cause problems well known to git-wordpress people such as database being out of sync, and problems with syncing /upload and its many thumbnails etc. At least with this model the development working tree exactly mirrored the production working tree and git pulls onto production were predicatable.

I decided to change to the following simplified model:

1) Prep development and then clone it to production via duplicator plugin (it does a simple mysqldump and zip). Production then starts to diverge from development as users upload their photos etc to production.

2) Version control on development only the files I am coding and changing and push them up to github.

3) Pull just these versioned files to production:
In production I run "git init"
then "git remote add github blabla"

At this point I am not sure how to pull the github files (which are a small number) into my production working directory without git pull deleting all my other files. In development as I change files my IDE phpstorm offers to add them automatically to my local repo and I push them to github.

But I dont want to have to then go into production and remember each file I added to the development repo then add each of those files individually to the production repo before doing a git pull from github (seems very inefficient). What I did that went wrong:

In production: "git add .", then "git pull production master".

I got a warning about overwriting and so I did "git reset --hard && git pull blahblah" and it deleted every file on production that wasn't versioned on development/github, leaving behind just the 3 files I had versioned.

Luckily I had a backup but clearly my understanding of git is limited. I would appreciate very much if anyone could share with me how they would achieve this usecase with git? Is the only solution to git add on production each file I add to the development git?

Answer (score 0):

The way to remember and think about this—which is a little self-contradictory, but it works out in the end—is to remember that Git doesn't work on or with *files*.  Git works with *commits*.

Of course, commits *contain* files, but the files that a Git commit contains are in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed format (sometimes very compressed), because *every* commit contains *all* the files, as a complete snapshot of all the files you saved into that commit at the time you made that commit.  I like to say that the files inside commits are in a freeze-dried format, because they can't actually be *used* for anything without first being rehydrated.

The freeze-dried files can't be *changed*, either.  This means they can be freely *shared* from one commit to any other: there's no risk of the committed file being changed in the older commit, so the newer commit can just re-use it directly.  There's no risk of the committed file being changed in the newer commit either, so any even-newer commit can continue re-using the old freeze-dried file, and so on.  The fact that you (and Git) literally cannot change *anything*, *ever*, about *any* existing commit means that each commit is great for archival.  But it also means that each commit is, by itself, completely useless for getting any actual work done, since to do any actual work you need to *change*—or add and/or remove—some file(s), and you can't do that within any commit.

Git therefore gives you a *work-tree*.  The work-tree is, quite simply, where you do your work.  The work-tree is not stored inside the repository proper, and is not transferred from one clone to another: **each clone has its own *private* work-tree.**

When you first make a new clone from some existing Git repository, your Git contacts that other Git, gets a list of *all* of its commits, and copies over *all* of those commits.  Since commits *are* the history, you now have every file ever committed, with all the (commit) history showing that, e.g., commit `G` is the parent of commit `H`,<sup>1</sup> and `G` has a parent `F`, and so on.  In any case, you currently have *no* files in the new empty work-tree that Git made to let the `git clone` have a place to put work files, but there's a *last* commit on `master`, which your Git can now extract.

To fill in your empty work-tree, Git will now take all the freeze-dried files in the snapshot `H` at the tip of `master` and rehydrate them.  The reconstituted, normal, everyday files, which you can actually see and work with, are now *there* in your work-tree, and off you go and do some work.

To *transfer* your new work to some *other* Git repository, though, you must package up everything as a new commit.  But Git doesn't make commits from the work-tree.  Instead, Git makes new commits from what Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or (occasionally especially in very old Git documentation) the *cache*.

What the index is, is a sort of staging area—hence that second name—that sits *between* your current commit (which we're calling `H`) and your work-tree.  Inside the commit, your files are freeze-dried and can't be changed.  There's an extra copy of those files in the index, though, and unlike the copy in the work-tree, this copy *can* be changed—well, *replaced*, really.  So, having changed the ordinary-format files in your work-tree, you must now run `git add` on each file to freeze-dry it and copy the new freeze-dried file into the index / staging-area.  The new copy *replaces* the old one.

If you make a totally-new file, you can `git add` it: that freeze-dries it, copies it into the index, and now there's a new file in the index / staging-area, right next to all the existing files in the index, ready to go.  And, you can completely *remove* a file, from *both* the index/staging-area *and* the work-tree, using `git rm`.

In any case, once you've updated (or removed) all the index copies of every updated or new (or removed) file, you are ready to run `git commit`.  This takes all the index files—which are all in the special freeze-dried format already—and snapshots them into a new commit.  Since this is a *new* commit, it gets a new, and totally unique to you, hash ID that *no* other Git *anywhere* has right now, but we'll just call it commit `I`.  The *parent* of new commit `I` is existing commit `H`, the one you extracted in order to *make* new commit `I`.  And now that you've made new commit `I`, Git can update your name `master` to remember the actual hash ID of `I`.  Since `I` remembers the actual hash ID of `H`, we say that `master` *points to* `I`, and `I` *points to* `H`, and we can draw this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <-- master
```

A good way to think of the index is that it contains *the next commit you will make*.  You manipulate it with `git add` and `git rm` (and occasionally `git reset`).  When you `git checkout` a commit, Git fills the index from the commit you check out.  When you make a new commit, Git permanently freezes all the files that are in the index *right then* into the new commit.

Note that the index, like the work-tree, is private to *this* Git repository.  It never gets transferred to any other Git repository.  Only *commits* get transferred—well, commits and (annotated) tag objects, and the files that go inside the commits (which might be tagged).  In any case, the index and work-tree are private; the *commits* are shared.  That, again, is part of why Git is all about *commits*.

---

<sup>1</sup>These are not real hash IDs.  Real commit hash IDs are those are big ugly random-looking things like `83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6`.  I like to use one-uppercase-letter stand-ins to talk about Git, because humans can relate to them.  The obvious problem with single uppercase letters is that they run out way too fast for a real repository, which could easily have many thousands of commits.  But they are OK for simple examples.

---

#### Transferring commits from Git to Git

Now that you've made new commit `I`, you can *send* it somewhere else, to another Git.  Your Git will call up their Git and say: *I have commit <hash-of-I>, do you have it?*  They will say no, of course, and your Git can then send them the commit, with all of its files.  Now they *do* have the new commit, using that same hash ID.  They'll update one of *their* names, maybe their `master` branch name, so that *they* can remember the real actual big ugly hash ID too.  If *their* `master` name remembered `H` before, it's safe for them to switch to `I`, because `I` remembers `H` as `I`'s parent.

This same process works in the other direction: if you cloned from some repository elsewhere—say, on GitHub—you can have your Git call up that repository again and find out which commits they have that you don't.  Your Git will then download those commits—with their contained, freeze-dried files inside them, yes, but it's not downloading *files*, it's downloading *commits*.

Let's say that you sent them your `I`, and then since then, they've added their own `J` and `K`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
               \
                J--K   <-- [received from them as their master]
```

Your own Git will remember the hash ID of `K` by writing it into your *remote-tracking name* `origin/master`.

You can now move your Git from your (now shared) commit `I` to the now-shared, made-by-them commit `K`, if you like.  To do so, you could `git checkout` the commit by its hash ID or by the name `origin/master`.  You can also *merge* your `master`—pointing, again / still, to the now-shared `I`—with their commit `K`.  Since there are no new commits of your own *after* `I`, your Git can do this by doing a *fast-forward* operation instead of a real merge.  That really amounts to: *check out commit `K`, and make the name `master` point to `K`.*

That is, after `git merge origin/master`, your Git will update your graph to read:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J--K   <-- master, origin/master
```

and you'll have commit `K` checked out in your work-tree.

#### Switching commits sometimes means *removing* work-tree files

Now, suppose that in order to get from `I` to `K`, whoever *made* `J` and then `K` *removed* a bunch of files, using `git rm` to tell Git: *remove this files from both index / staging-area, and work-tree.*  Let's say whoever made `J` did:

```
git rm file1 file2 file3
git commit -m "make commit J"
```

These three files *are* in commit `I` (because they came out of commit `I` in the first place).  They're *still* in commit `I`, because no existing commit can ever be changed.  But they're *not* in commit `J`, because then-new commit `J` got made after removing them from the index.

Then they went on to remove some more files:

```
git rm file4 file5
git commit -m "make commit K"
```

So `file4` and `file5` *are* in commits `I` and `J`, but are *not* in commit `K`.

When you have your Git switch from `H` to `K`, your Git will therefore *remove* all five files from your work-tree.  They're safely stored in `I`, and safely (and forever!) *not*-stored in `K`.  Move back to `J` and two of the five files come back; move back to `I` and the other three come back; move to `K` and they all go away.  That's OK though: they're still there, in commit `I`, and Git is all about *commits*.

#### Untracked files

Now, the fact that you *have* a work-tree, which stores ordinary non-Git-ified files in their ordinary, non-freeze-dried format, means that you can, at any time, create files that you *never* `git add` and `git commit`.  These files exist in your work-tree but Git has no knowledge about them.  Because they are not in the *index*, they are *untracked files*.

But what about files like `file1` through `file5`?  They *were* in the index at one point—when we had commit `I` out—and they aren't if we have commit `K` out now.  If you create a *new* `file1` right now, that file will exist in the work-tree and will be untracked.  But if you go back to commit `I`, Git will have to *overwrite* the untracked work-tree `file1` with the `file1` it rehydrates out of commit `I`.  Then when you go back to `K`, Git will *remove* the rehydrated `file1`.  The `file1` you had in your work-tree while you had `K` out is now *gone*, and *there is no copy of that file in Git at all*.

This is the danger of accidentally tracking (adding to the index) some file that you never meant to track.  It's now permanently stored in the commits that you made from that index, at that time.  If you *extract* one of those commits, the file is tracked because it gets copied into your index.  If you then move *off* that commit to one where the file doesn't exist, it gets *removed* from your index **and from your work-tree**, and that's where the pain comes in.

The TL;DR summary is: be careful what you commit, because if you have to remove something, you set up these little time-bombs for other people, or even for yourself if you have forgotten about this.  Untracked files *aren't* stored in Git, but files that have the same *name* might exist in some other commit, and if you check out such a commit, that can *overwrite* your untracked files.

If you have a need for, e.g., prototype configurations, where you want to show how to configure something, without actually configuring it, name these things such that they won't collide with the *actual* configuration, if that's not part of the repository.  For instance, instead of `.htaccess`, you might commit a `.htaccess.example`.  Then it's OK for that file to be in every commit, and for `.htaccess` itself to never be in *any* commit.  Git won't ever remove the active work-tree `.htaccess` file (that's not committed and is not in any historical commit) and will only update the `.htaccess.example` file when switching from commit to commit.

Comment: Thankyou Torek for such an extensive explanation of how GIT works - I have printed it out to digest and hope it will be of use to others here on Stack.

Comment: I am going to ask a new question which is much more specific with code and concise.